# Dynaconf enviroment variables don't override existing

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, config

```
dynaconf[yaml]==2.2.3
```

settings.yml:

```
dynaconf_merge: true
default:
  POSTGRES:
    host: localhost
    port: 5432
    database: cool_db
```

config.py

```
from dynaconf import LazySettings

settings = LazySettings(ENVVAR_PREFIX_FOR_DYNACONF=False, DOTENV_OVERRIDE_FOR_DYNACONF=True)
```

.env

```
POSTGRES__host=foobar
```

Result: we have two keys in settings:

```
settings.POSTGRES.host == 'localhost'
settings.POSTGRES.HOST == 'foobar'
```

Why does this happen? I detect that it had something to do with the system environment, but I did not determine what. This code runs in Windows 10. Also we testing on debian-based distributions - result is different.